# Homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $n^2$ indeterminates that cannot be the sum of the terms of degree $n$ in $P_1Q_1 + ... + P_k Q_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, finite-fields

This is a "difficult" exercise taken from Bourbaki's "Commutative Algebra". I have no idea on how to solve it, nor tackle it.

Let $K$ be a finite field. Prove that for all $k \in \mathbb N$, there exists $n_k \in \mathbb N$ such that : for all $n \geq n_k$, there exists a homogeneous polynomial $F_n \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n^2}]$ ($n^2$ indeterminates) of degree $n$ that *cannot* be the sum of the terms of degree $n$ in *any* polynomial of the form $P_1Q_1 + \ldots + P_k Q_k$, where $P_i$ and $Q_i \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n^2}]$ are polynomials *without constant term*.

Does anyone have a hint or an idea on how to solve this ? Also, I really cannot see how the fact that $K$ is a finite field will help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Compute the number of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ (this number is finite because $K$ is a finite field).

**Solution** (spoilerised, in case you would like to try the hint first)**.**

> This problem is more combinatorics than algebra. Let's first compute the number of monomials of (total) degree $n$. It's given by the number of ways to choose $n$ variables from the $n^2$ variables $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n^2}$, with repetitions being allowed. Thus it equals $\binom{n^2+n-1}n$. This implies that the number of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ equals $$|K|^{\binom{n^2+n-1}n}\,,$$as there are $|K|$ choices of coefficient for each of the $\binom{n^2+n-1}n$ monomials.
> Next, observe that we may assume that all $P_i$ and $Q_i$ have degree $\leq n-1$. Indeed, all terms in $P_i$ of degree $\geq n$ won't contribute to the degree $n$ part of $P_iQ_i$,  since $Q_i$ has no constant term, and vice versa. So let's compute the number of polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$ (from now on we ignore the requirement that there be no constant coefficients, since it will be irrelevant for the estimate). The number of polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$ in $n^2$ variables $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n^2}$ is the same as the number of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n-1$ in $n^2+1$ variables $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n^2},t$, since we can use the additional variable $t$ to homogenise  in a unique way. Hence we can use a similar calculation as above to see that there are $$|K|^{\binom{n^2+1+(n-1)-1}{n-1}}$$polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$. Hence there are at most $$|K|^{2k\binom{n^2+n-1}{n-1}}$$choices for $P_1,\dotsc,P_k,Q_1,\dotsc,Q_k$ (under the assumption that all have degree $\leq n-1$).
> Finally, observe that $\binom{n^2+n-1}n=n\binom{n^2+n-1}{n-1}$. Hence, for $n>2k$ we see that there are more choices of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ than there are choices of $P_1,\dotsc,P_k,Q_1,\dotsc,Q_k$ (of degrees $\leq n-1$), which proves the desired claim. $\square$